# Erro MySQL servidor diferente do que eu configurei

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando PHP e tentei me conectar a um servidor diferente do que o site está rodando, usando a função:

```
$servidor = "example.com";
$usuario = "meu_usuario";
$senha = "senha";
$conecta = mysql_connect($servidor, $usuario, $senha) or print(mysql_error());
```

E dá o erro

> Access denied for user 'meu_usuario'@'outro_servidor.com.br'

Parece que ele não enxerga o servidor que estou tentando alcançar.

Não importa qual servidor eu coloque na variavel $servidor, sempre o que aparece no erro é que ele tentou se conectar ao servidor atual. Não uso um banco de dados no mesmo servidor pois não tenho acesso ao mesmo.

Comment: O MySQL do servidor precisa estar configurado para dar acesso ao `meu_usuario@servidor_que_está_hospedado_o_site`.

Comment: Não é isso, em outro servidor a conexão funciona normalmente, o problema é que o servidor que estou usando parece forçar o domínio para usar o próprio. As permissões estão corretas já. O problema é que tento me conectar no servidor "X" mas dá erro dizendo que não foi possivel se conectar ao servidor "Y".

Comment: @rafaslide veja a resposta que eu dei na pergunta linkada, para ver como autorizar o usuário. O problema é a autorização nos dois casos, teste autorizar o user no servidor MySQL, que provavelmente o erro é resolvido.

Comment: @rafaslide mas se fazendo a autorização o problema não for resolvido, acrescente os detalhes aqui. PS: Indicar como duplicata não invalida sua pergunta, é só um meio de apontar para a solução apresentada anteriormente, como forma de organização do site. Isto não significa que sua pergunta tenha problemas, fique tranquilo. E se sua necessidade DE FATO for diferente daquela, você pode editar a pergunta com mais detalhes. (mas eu sugeriria tentar a solução apresentada lá, grande chance de ser o que você precisa).

Comment: o problema é: estou tentando me conectar ao servidor "example.com", quando faço o requisição ele retorna um erro do MySQL dizendo "Access denied for user 'usuario'@'servidorestranho.com.br'" ou seja, eu estou querendo me conectar a um servidor, mas quem está recebendo a conexão é outro servidor.

Comment: Não, a mensagem diz que você está tentando se conectar *a partir do servidorestranho.com.br*, que é onde está o seu site. Lá no example.com você precisa autorizar o usuário meu_usuario a acessar a partir daí (portanto meu_usuario@servidor_que_está_hospedado_o_site).

Comment: Agora sim entendi, perdão pela dificuldade. Vou tentar e posto aqui um feedback.

Comment: Sem problemas! Espero que consiga resolver agora.

Comment: Não rolou, coloquei o endereço que retornava no erro nas permissões do MySQL Remoto do cPanel do server que vai receber os dados. Lá já constava uma entrada para '%', de qualquer forma coloquei o endereço mas não consegui. Continua o mesmo erro.

Comment: @rafaslide Tente criar um outro user com uma senha nova pra você ter certeza que o problema não é de credenciais. Além disso, lembre de dar as permissões para este user.

Comment: Ok, vou tentar amanhã apenas, por hoje não tenho mais tempo. Obrigado, assim que tiver resposta venho aqui

Comment: O problema era a senha, tinha muitos caracteres especiais. Obrigado pela ajuda!